# Files related to Elan Touchpad driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad

Two weeks ago, I was facing BSOD error: Driver State Power Failure on my laptop.
I was told to update all of my drivers from Lenovo's website.

Under Mouse, Pen and Keyboard drivers I was supposed to download and install Synaptics Touchpad Driver, but I installed both Synaptics Touchpad Driver and Elan Touchpad driver (At the time, I did not know which one I was supposed to install).

Later, I deleted C:\drivers\elantech\ thinking it was of no use.

Today, I noticed a process named ETDService.exe in the task manager. I googled and found out that it's related to Elan Touchpad Driver.

I right-clicked on the process> open file location and I found the following files in C:\Windows\System32:

1. ETDApix.dll (497kb)
2. ETDCtrlHelper.exe (390kb)
3. ETDFavorite.dll (460kb)
4. ETDService.exe (243kb)

All are related to Elan Touchpad driver, but weren't they supposed to be in C:\drivers\elantech\ (which I deleted) or   C:\Program Files\elantech\ (I don't have this folder)?

Is this malware/trojan? Should I delete them from system32 or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: System32 is legitimate, Do Not delete it, drivers are stored in various places but most drivers load and run from the system32 folder

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't supposed to download Elan driver. In device manager, under "mice and pointing devices" I have "Synaptics Pointing device" not "Elan pointing device".
Why are these process running if I have a touchpad of a different manufacturer?
Thanks for commenting.